# The calling thread cannot access this object (rewrited but same error)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a MainFrame window with imageViewer control on it. Also there is my dll which calculates changes for the image all was working fine before I decided to add ProgressDialog.(( The Idea was - firstly I am loading the image via dll to main frame (this still OK). Then if user clicks button then show ProgressDialog and in worker.DoWork create new image via the same dllwrapper class (I am using "new") 
All seems to be ok but when i am trying to set my currentImage property of imageviewer control (this is nothing more then setter for Image)it show me this error! 
This is the code of my userButtonClickHandler from where I am launching ProgressDialog:

```
void OnThumbnailClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pd = new ProgressDlg();
    pd.Cancel += CancelProcess;

    int max = 1000;
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher pdDispatcher = pd.Dispatcher;
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    LibWrap lwrap = new LibWrap();//!NEW instance for dll wrapper!

    worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        imageViewer.CurrentImage = lwrap.engine2(BitmapFrame.Create(MyPrj.App.draggedImage));//ERROR IS HERE!!!//The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
        //what process?? 
    };

    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        pd.Close();
    };

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    pd.ShowDialog();
}
```

There is function from the same MainFrame class for canceling (There is OK too)

```
void CancelProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   worker.CancelAsync();
 }
```

This is class for ProgressDlg (it has nothing more then progress bar and cancel button):

```
public partial class ProgressDlg : Window
    {
        public ProgressDlg()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string ProgressText
        {
            set
            {
                this.lblProgress.Content = value;
            }
        }
        public int ProgressValue
        {
            set
            {
                this.progress.Value = value;
            }
        }
        public event EventHandler Cancel = delegate { };
        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cancel(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am working with this problem for (almost) two days and still couldn't find the solution. Help me please if you have an idea.

1 UPDATE
It seems to me that you was right about this threads - when I am trying to load previously loaded(initial) image (from the main thread) -it loads OK but if I am trying libWrap it fails due to processes conflict!

```
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
            {
imageViewer.Width = 1000;//work!
  imageViewer.CurrentImage = MyPrj.App.draggedImage;//Work!
imageViewer.CurrentImage = lwrap.engine2(BitmapFrame.Create(MyPrj.App.draggedImage));//Fail =(!

}
```

2 UPDATE
I have tried this construction OnThumbnailClick

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
imaeViewer.CurrentImage = lwrap.engine2(BitmapFrame.Create(FXPhotoStudio.App.draggedImage));
}
```

This caused same error/ Perhaps it will be correct to pass this value in MainThread (UI)? But I have no idea how.( I couldnot use serializers - becouse it is rapidly calling operation and this images are temporary/

Comment: possible duplicate of [The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502033/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

Comment: Don't just repost a slightly changed version of your previous question - edit the old question instead.

Comment: This is not repost - I have rewrited code! And there is one class less then in previouse sample but I have same error and still have no idea what to do!

Comment: But it's a repost in terms of being the same problem. It would still have been better to edit the existing post.

Comment: You cannot bind to the UI in the DoWork as it is not on the thread that createdd the UI control.  You need to create the image in DoWork then bind the image in the RunWorkerCompleted as the is the purpose of the RunWorkerCompleted. See anser from Henk.  The purpose of Background worker is to take care of many of the threading and dispatcher issues.   If this is just one less class than before but the same problem then it  should not be a new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF cannot alter items that were created on another thread.

So if you create an `ImageViewer` on one thread, you cannot alter it's properties on another thread.

Instead, use the `Dispatcher`, which is WPF's internal message queue for the main UI thread, to update your objects.

Or, use [Henk's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8507106/302677) to do your work on another thread, but return the result to the main thread so it can update your ImageViewer's properties

Comment: So I must write something like : 

void OnThumbnailClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ new Thread in which Henk's code running? But how I could trans the data to main thread? It may cause the same error! I couldnot save file to disk(( (serialize)

Comment: @PapaJohn Henk's code should work. It is saying to create your image on another thread, then pass the result back to the main UI thread (which is what `RunWorkerCompleted` will execute on) where it can set the `CurrentImage` property of your `ImageViewer` to the item that was created on the background thread.

Comment: Hello Rachel )) You was helped me once. If I create image in new process in `worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args) 
{ ..here..? 
}`is that right?

Comment: @PapaJohn You can't have a background thread create the `Image` UI Element because when you assign it, WPF will try to set it's `Parent` property to `imageViewer` and an exception will be thrown because the `Image` was created on another thread. For that kind of situation, use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to run something asynchronously on the main UI thread, instead of on a `BackgroundWorker` which will run it on another thread.

Comment: @PapaJohn Based on your edit, it sounds like `lwrap.engine2(BitmapFrame.Create(...));` is creating a UI Element on a background thread. I would investigate that and see if you can switch it to create UI Elements on the main thread.

Comment: Rachel I have updated my post - please see Update 2. (I am trying to use BeginInvoke)

Comment: @PapaJohn According to MSDN's page for BitmapFrame, `Any BitmapFrame returned from a decoder is always frozen. If you require a modifiable copy, you must first create a copy of the BitmapFrame by using the Clone method.` Why don't you give that a try?

Comment: engine2 returns BitmapImage, not a frame. I am trying to make a sample with only mainframe and this progressdialog - to see  this problem in most easy way. Could you recommend something to read about that threading value passing ?

Comment: @PapaJohn I would first remove all threading and run everything unthreaded. This will tell you if the problem is with your `lwrap.engine2(BitmapFrame.Create(...));` call or not.

Comment: I tested it before)) engine2 is working. Buy the way I am using it to create first picture for MainFrame but not in this MAGIC ProgressDialog. Thank you anyway, Rachel. it seems that it is too sophisticated problem

Answer (score 2):

You need at least these changes:

```
worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
   args.Result = lwrap.engine2(BitmapFrame.Create(MyPrj.App.draggedImage));
};

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
  if (args.Error != null)
  { ... }  // handle error
  else if (args.Cancelled)
  { ... } // handle Cancel
  else
  {
    imageViewer.CurrentImage = args.Result;
  }
  pd.Close();
}
```

I'm not sure if it's enough but try again.

Comment: what is 'e' ? RoutedEventArgs e has no Result or Canceled

Comment: same.. perhaps that is becouse I am trying accessing main process((

Comment: `set
            {
                if (_currentImage != value)
                {
                    _currentImage = value;
                    this.imgCurrent.Source = _currentImage;//Error is here
                }
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

The imageViewer was created on the main thread of the application (which is appropriate because it is a UI control).  UI controls can ONLY be accessed by the thread which created it, and that thread must have its own dispatcher (by which I mean message loop).

Remove the threading code, and it will work.

If you want this to popup the window and then show the image when the conversion completes, you will have to store the returned image in a variable until you return to the main thread, and then make the assignment to the imageViewer.

Comment: Remove the threading code, and it will work. - How ? I need the progressDialog runnig simultaniuosly with calculating process and if user clicks cancel on this dialog I must abort calculation process. With aborting - there is no problem(I have tested) but this is in the same process